# Unable to hit custom AuthenticationProvider using Spring security 5.1.1

Tags: spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I'm using Spring security 5.1.1. I'm trying to create two security entryPoints for my application: one for REST and another for the secured urls of the application. I've created `CustomAuthenticationProvider` by implementing `AuthenticationProvider` for the authenticationManager.
I'm following the examples in :
[Spring Security for a REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security) and
[Spring Security – Two Security Realms in one Application](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/spring-security-two-security-realms-in-one-application/)

But on the login page, when I enter username and password it doesn't hit the `CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` method at all, rather it goes to logout.html.
Below is my xml snippet of http:

```
<!-- Configuration for API -->

<security:http entry-point-ref="restAuthEntryPoint" pattern="/api/**"  use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**"  access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_DRIVER','ROLE_PARENT') and isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/driver/**"  access="hasRole('ROLE_DRIVER') and isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/parent/**"  access="hasRole('ROLE_PARENT') and isAuthenticated()"/>

    <form-login
      authentication-success-handler-ref="apiSuccessHandler"
      authentication-failure-handler-ref="apiFailureHandler" />

    <custom-filter ref="apiAuthenticationFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <logout />
</security:http>

<beans:bean id="apiAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="restAuthEntryPoint"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="restAuthEntryPoint" 
    class="com.main.sts.api.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<beans:bean id="apiSuccessHandler"
  class="com.main.sts.api.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="apiFailureHandler" class=
  "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<!-- Configuration for Rest-API finished-->

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/school_admin/*"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SCHOOLADMIN','ROLE_GUEST','ROLE_SCHOOLTEACHER','ROLE_PARENT')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>

    <!-- <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="userAuthenticationProcessingFilter" /> -->

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/404" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/logout.html">

    </session-management>
    <sec:headers >
        <sec:cache-control />
        <sec:hsts/>
    </sec:headers>
</security:http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager> 

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.main.sts.util.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="loginService" ref="loginService" />
</beans:bean>
```

Even if I commented out the configuration for the REST-api, still I don't get hit to that class.

Here's my CustomAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

    // **I never hit this class**
}
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

filter is defined correctly in web.xml:

```
      <filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
```

springSecurityFilterChain /*

In the login jsp, I've setup form as below:

```
        <form class="form-vertical login-form" name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
```

I can't access secured urls, it takes me to the login page; this means - this filter works. But why can't I hit CustomAuthenticationProvider? Why does it go to logout.html???

I've also tried by implementing custom filter (which eventually sets authenticationManager as the property); but still no luck.

I've also checked the log files but nothing in there.

BTW, if I try to access through `curl`, I get `Http status 403 (forbidden). The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.`

`curl -i -X POST -d username=admin -d password=Admin123 http://localhost:8080/sts/api/login`

Please help me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah, finally I've found the issue.The code base which I originally started with was implemented on Spring 2.5. I've upgraded Spring version to 5.1. Basically  /j_spring_security_check , j_username and j_password have been deprecated.
Now I've changed my jsp accordingly and it works now.

It's weird that there was no error or warning message.